# How do you find the relationship between the change of length in materials due to thermal stress?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've googled this question but it seems that no one has talked about it. If I have for example, aluminum in between 2 walls made of steel, and I want to find the stress inside steel, how would I develop the equation to relate the two materials?

I know that if aluminum was in between to rigid walls and that its length cannot change anymore, the equation would be:
dL(thermo) + dL(mechanical) = dL(total)
dL(total) = 0

Comment: Try searching for "thermal expansion" plus "multilayer" or "composite". Whole books have been written about this subject. You can find the change in dimensions of the composite material by minimizing the total strain energy of the system.

Comment: First you calculate the increase in length if it were free to expand.  Then you calculate the force you need to apply to compress it back  down to its original length.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I believe Tee Hee already understands that technique from the second paragraph of the question. The question is rather how to analyze the problem if the aluminum and the steel each deforms while remaining perfectly bonded. I wrote up a quick summary as an answer.

Comment: I didn't interpret his question as a composites problem.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach for finding the equilibrium deformation (assuming linear elasticity and small deformations) is to minimize the total strain energy with respect to changes in deformation. I'll go through a simple example.

Let's assume that two long strips of equal volume made of aluminum and steel are connected down their lengths.

The strain energy $U=\frac{1}{2}V\sigma\epsilon=\frac{1}{2E}V\sigma^2$ for a single strip of material $i$ that is constrained to lengthen by a distance $\Delta L$ from its original length $L_0$ while undergoing a temperature change is $$U_i=\frac{1}{2}V\sigma_i\epsilon_i=\frac{V}{2E_i}\sigma_i^2=\frac{VE_i}{2}\left(\frac{\Delta L-L_0\alpha_i\Delta T}{L_{0}}\right)^2$$

(You can verify the stress term by imagining the strip lengthening freely to $L_0\alpha_i\Delta T$ under the temperature change and then compressing it to some degree.) Note that by assuming long strips, we can ignore any lateral stresses.

Thus, the total strain energy is

$$U=\frac{VE_\mathrm{Al}}{2}\left(\frac{\Delta L-L_{0}\alpha_\mathrm{Al}\Delta T}{L_{0}}\right)^2+\frac{VE_\mathrm{St}}{2}\left(\frac{\Delta L-L_{0} \alpha_\mathrm{St}\Delta T}{L_0}\right)^2$$

Set $\frac{dU}{d\Delta L}$ equal to zero:

$$VE_\mathrm{Al}\left(\frac{\Delta L-L_{0}\alpha_\mathrm{Al}\Delta T}{L_{0}^2}\right)+VE_\mathrm{St}\left(\frac{\Delta L-L_{0}\alpha_\mathrm{St}\Delta T}{L_0^2}\right)=0$$

$$\Delta L=L_0\Delta T\left(\frac{\alpha_\mathrm{Al}E_\mathrm{Al}+\alpha_\mathrm{St}E_\mathrm{St}}{E_\mathrm{Al}+E_\mathrm{St}}\right)$$

Note that if one strip is removed (i.e., its stiffness is taken as zero), then this equation reverts back to simple uniaxial thermal expansion. In addition, if the stiffness of one material dominates over the other's, then its thermal expansion coefficient also dominates in terms of the total deformation.

You may have noticed that you can arrive at the same answer if you assume that the force between the two strips must be equal and opposite. That's to be expected, since the derivative of an energy with respect to a distance gives a force. But the strain energy minimization approach is more general and easier to apply in the case of complex geometries and multiple components.

The analysis of perfectly bonded plates is going to be somewhat more complex because you have a biaxial stress state, implying lateral stresses and the possibility that Poisson's ratio makes an appearance. In any case, this simple example should give you a sense of how to perform the analysis.